# ext4 loopback device, Buffer I/O Error on reboot

Tags: mount, ext4, loopback

I am trying to mount a loopback device on my ext4 formatted ssd drive.
I get these errors when I reboot on Linux kernel 2.6.38.8

```
Buffer I/O error on device loop1, logical block 0
```

Here is what I do:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/s/lodev bs=4096 count=250000
# mkfs.ext4 /mnt/s/lodev
# mount -n -o loop,rw /mnt/s/lodev /mnt/test
```

The loopback mount is successful, but on reboot I get errors as mentioned above. Even mouting with 'sync','data=writeback' does not help.

I tried to losetup a device, but see the same behavior.
I also reformatted the base device and created the loopback device and mounted as above, I still see these errors. I do not see them when I format them as vfat.

Appreciate any suggestions on this problem.

Comment: What command are you using to mount the drive after a reboot?  Are you unmounting the loopback device before rebooting?

Comment: I am not unmounting the loopback device before reboot. I simply do a mount -n -o loop,rw <loopback device> <mount point>

Comment: By <loopback device> do you mean `/dev/loop1` or `/mnt/s/lodev`?

Comment: Hi: I mean /mnt/s/lodev, I also tried using /dev/loop1 after performing losetup /dev/loop1 /mnt/s/lodev.